# calling perfectly forwarded lambda

Tags: c++, forwarding, perfect

I have the following class which stores a perfectly forwarded reference to a function:

```
template <class F> 
class Visitor
{
public:
    Visitor(F &&f) : _f(std::forward<F>(f)) 
    {
    }

    xt::LOOP_CONTROL OnElem(xvi::Elem &elem)
    {
        return _f(elem);

        // or should it be: 
        // return std::forward<F>(_f)(elem);
    }

private:
    F &&_f;
};
```

Wondering if it makes a difference to call `_f(elem)` or `std::forward<F>(_f)(elem);`?

Comment: Typically you'd forward the arguments, not the function itself.

Comment: Even though *technically* one can ref-qualify `operator()` to work on either lvalues or rvalues, I don't believe it's performed a lot in practice. It's very improbable `_f(elem)` will be broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambda cannot have ref qualified `operator ()` currently, so for them, both forms are equivalent.

For custom functor, it might differ with `std::forward<F>(_f)(elem);`:

```
struct MyFunctor
{
    xt::LOOP_CONTROL operator()(xvi::Elem &elem) &  { std::cout << "lvalue"; return {};}
    xt::LOOP_CONTROL operator()(xvi::Elem &elem) && { std::cout << "rvalue"; return {};}
};

xvi::Elem elem;
Visitor<MyFunctor>(MyFunctor{}).OnElem(elem); // rvalue
MyFunctor func;
Visitor<MyFunctor&>(func).OnElem(elem); // lvalue
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I have not seen the need for ref qualified functions yet, but maybe this will come handy someday.

Comment: The one I see which might be useful it to allow lifetime extension `auto&& extended = Tmp().getObj();` with `Obj getObj() &&` (return by value here to allow lifetime extension)/`Obj& getObj() &`/`const Obj& getObj() const &`.

Comment: Thanks again @Jarod42 that is a good use case.